# Reconocer mayusculas o minusculas en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un `TextBox` en el cual se escanean letras y hace una busqueda en `Access`, el problema que tengo es que al estar el teclado en mayúscula escanea las letras en minúscula y viceversa, y a la hora de hacer la busqueda da un error en el formato de la variable y es por que estan en minúsculas.

Como puedo hacer que identifique cuando son mayúsculas o minúsculas??
esto es lo que tengo.

```
public string selcopert()
    {
        int decValue = 0;
        string query="";
        if (opertname.StartsWith("~") && opertname.EndsWith("~") && opertname.Length > 1)
        {
            string oprt = Regex.Replace(opertname, @"^~UMIH\|(.*)~$", "$1");
            decValue = int.Parse(oprt, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            query = "SELECT * where op = '" + decValue + "' ";
        }
        else
        {
            query = "Select * op where = '" + opertname + "' ";
        }
        string op="";
        SqlConnection cone = new SqlConnection(cc.consql);
        cone.Open();
        SqlCommand coms = new SqlCommand(query, cone);
        using (SqlDataReader read1 = coms.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (read1.Read())
            {
                op = read1[0].ToString();
            }
        }
        cone.Close();
        return op;
    }
```

O tambien que el `Regex.Replace` reconozca mayúsculas y minúsculas, pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: En principio si le añades /i regex deberia ignorar mayusculas/minusculas.

Comment: Donde exactamente?

Comment: Al final del patron de Regex.Replace.

Comment: Si quieres siempre validar letras mayúsculas, por qué no aplicas un ToUpper() a tu variable string?

Comment: Mas alla de todo, los querys estan mal..

Comment: Ademas esto no puede ser "da un error en el formato de la variable y es por que estan en minúsculas" que tiene que ver mayusculas y minusculas con la variable? si es string guarda lo que le mandes.

Comment: Mi recomendación sería que siempre busques mayúsculas con ToUpper()  o minúsculas con ToLower() así como lo comenta @SergioParra, independientemente si está activado o no el bloque de mayúsculas. Además que mi recomendación es que nunca realices *queries* dinámicos, es muy suceptible a **SQL Injection**

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes problemas con el Caps Lock, pulsa en esta secuencia al mismo tiempo estos botones:

> CAPS LOCK+CTRL+SHIFT
>
> **[Fuente](https://superuser.com/a/870667/702051)**

En cuanto a tu código, sigue las recomendaciones que te han dado en los comentarios:

1. Coloca ToUpperInvariant() a tus variables.

Ejemplo:

```
// Con este método vuelves todos los caracteres a mayúscula.
string opertname = TextBox1.Text.ToUpperInvariant();
```